# Why does the last line compare $t2 to $s0?

Tags: mips

This is exercise 2.29 from the 5th edition of *Computer Organisation and Design* by David A. Patterson and John L. Hennessy:

```
...

    addi $t1, $0, $0
    LOOP :
    lw  $s1, 0($s0)
    add $s2, $s2, $s1
    addi $s0, $s0, 4
    addi $t1, $t1, 1
    slti $t2, $t1, 100
    bne $t2, $s0, LOOP
...
    i = $t1
    $s2 = result
    $s0 = base address of MemArray
```

I'm supposed to translate this into C code, and I get:

```
for(int i =0 ;i<100;i++)
{
    result += MemArray[i];
}
```

This is the answer, but why does the last line of MIPS code compare `$t2` with `$s0`? `$s0` is the base address of `MemArray`. Shouldn't the comparison be to the zero register, in order for the loop to continue?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this is an error in the book; the correct comparison should be with `$0`, so `$s0` may just be a typo. However, it is not mentioned in [the errata](https://booksite.elsevier.com/9780124077263/downloads/COD5e_errata_09-2014.pdf) for the book's fifth edition.